# Window.Callback is overwritten by Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-toolbar

I found that in `setActionBar` method from `Activity`:

```
public void setActionBar(@Nullable Toolbar toolbar) {
    final ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    if (ab instanceof WindowDecorActionBar) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("This Activity already has an action bar supplied " +
                "by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set " +
                "android:windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.");
    }

    // If we reach here then we're setting a new action bar
    // First clear out the MenuInflater to make sure that it is valid for the new Action Bar
    mMenuInflater = null;

    // If we have an action bar currently, destroy it
    if (ab != null) {
        ab.onDestroy();
    }

    if (toolbar != null) {
        final ToolbarActionBar tbab = new ToolbarActionBar(toolbar, getTitle(), this);
        mActionBar = tbab;
        mWindow.setCallback(tbab.getWrappedWindowCallback());
    } else {
        mActionBar = null;
        // Re-set the original window callback since we may have already set a Toolbar wrapper
        mWindow.setCallback(this);
    }

    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

As you can see there `mWindow.setCallback(tbab.getWrappedWindowCallback())` is called with wrapped callback. And if we check implementation of `ToolbarAractionBar`:

```
ToolbarActionBar(Toolbar toolbar, CharSequence title, Window.Callback windowCallback) {
    mDecorToolbar = new ToolbarWidgetWrapper(toolbar, false);
    mWindowCallback = new ToolbarCallbackWrapper(windowCallback);
    mDecorToolbar.setWindowCallback(mWindowCallback);
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(mMenuClicker);
    mDecorToolbar.setWindowTitle(title);
}

public Window.Callback getWrappedWindowCallback() {
    return mWindowCallback;
}
```

It wraps last parameter of constructor, which was `this` (instance of `Activity`).

The problem appears if before calling `setActionBar` we set our own implementation of `Window.Callback` (that correctly wraps original one). In this case not our implementation is wrapped by `ToolbarActionBar` but original one.

It would not be a problem if `getWindow().getCallback()` used instead of `this` as `ToolbarActionBar` constructor parameter. So it looks like a bug in android sdk.

**The question is**: does anyone know how to deal with such situation or some workaround for that issue? (lets assume that we should set our callback before adding action bar)

---

btw. `setSupportActionBar` looks not the same but very similar and have the same issue.